# upgrade of civicrm fails with parse error

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I have a wordpress site with the civicrm plugin installed. We are still on 4.6, the latest in that branch. But we wanted to try out the latest version, which is 5.16.
I cloned the site and in that clone, I installed the zipfile of the new version , using the checklist for the 4.6 upgrades I did before.

When I had finished all steps and try to reload the site, it comes with an error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in public_html/civicrm-nw/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/league/csv/src/functions.php on line 33
```

I can enter recovery mode, but I have really no idea what I should do now. Should I try an earlier 5-version, or should I first upgrade to 4.7?

thanks for helping, Ruud

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your server has php 5.x. You need to use php 7.x for recent versions of CiviCRM.

See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version

Comment: hi dement, thanks helping me to look for the problem in the right place. Changing the PHP version via cpanel>software>php version brought me in the situation where the homepage is loaded. There is another problem now, but I am a step further. thanks a ton!