# Installation de civicrm sur worpress

Tags: wordpress

I installed civicrm on wordpress, and when I want to configure it: I fall on THIS MESSAGE /
Thank you for helping me.

### philippe

### Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '{' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-www\secret_defense\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\vendor\league\csv\src\functions.php on line 33

Ligne 33 : function bom_match(string $str): string
    {
static $list;

```
    $list = $list ?? (new ReflectionClass(ByteSequence::class))->getConstants();

    foreach ($list as $sequence) {
        if (0 === strpos($str, $sequence)) {
            return $sequence;
        }
    }

    return '';
```

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the same as [upgrade of civicrm fails with parse error](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/upgrade-of-civicrm-fails-with-parse-error). You need to have php 7.x on the server not php 5.x.

Comment: thank you, and good day.